# How to get number from last row of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am very newbie to Excel.

I have created invoice with 3 sheets.

- One is to store an invoice data.
- Sheet1 is invoice. In this invoice sheet, I have created a button that clears invoice data for new invoice.
- My invoice datas are stored in Sheet3.

when I add new invoice, invoice number will be generated automatically and it is the number from Sheet3's last A column's value+1

For example:
If sheet3 A columns last cell has invoice number 1001
then sheet1 H3 will be 1002

I think you guys are understanding my English.
Please help

Answer (score 3):

To return the contents of the last cell in Sheet3!ColumnA, you can use this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN(Sheet3!$A:$A)>0),Sheet3!$A:$A)
```

This is the array form of the `LOOKUP` function.

- 1/(LEN(...) returns an array of values of either 1, or `DIV/0` errors.
- Since *lookup_value* is 2, and since this must be greater than any value in `lookup_vector`, the function will match the last non-error value in the list, and return the corresponding value from `result_vector`

However, if your Invoice numbers are merely sequential numbers, then the last number would be given by the formula:

```
=MAX(Sheet3!$A:$A)
```

and you would just add one to that value.

Answer (score 1):

In H3 write:

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!A:A,MAX((Sheet3!A:A<>"")*(ROW(Sheet3!A:A))))+1
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>
A:A is the column in sheet3 where you have the last invoice number

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply.

its working when i put this formula directly to cell.

i think i was not asking well..

i have created a button with a name "New invoice" 
when i click that button, Sheet1 H3 will change to sheet3's Last A coloumn value +1

i have  attached the picture for your ref.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bT8F.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQSMe.jpg)

Note : if Sheet3 Last A column (in this picture is A30) is 1000 then when i click New button (on sheet1) H3 will generate